# How do I move text without moving everything else?

Tags: html, css

I would like to move the words "Social Media", above the two icons as a title. The problem I'm having is moving the title without moving the icons and the book button.

Could you please help?

```css
.icons{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: blue;
  padding-top: 250px;
  padding-left: 110px;
}
.book {
  padding-left: 43.5%;
}
.book button {
  background-color: #F6B2A2; 
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
.book a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="socialm">
    <h2>Social Media</h2>
</div>
<div class="icons">
        <a href="page2.php"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
        <a href="page2.php"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="book">
    <a href="page2.php"><button>Book</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: But... isn't it already *above* the icons?

Comment: can you clarify *moving above* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `display: block` and a `display: inline-block` for your icons in your css:

```
.socialm {
  display: block;
}

.icons{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: blue;
  padding-top: 250px;
  padding-left: 110px;
}

.book {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 43.5%;
}

.book button {
  background-color: #F6B2A2; 
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.book a {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another div that wraps both the header tag and the icons. Add your padding to that div to keep the two pieces together and move them both at the same time.

```css
.top{
  padding-left: 43.5%;
}

.icons{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: blue;
  padding-top: 250px;
  
}
.book {
  padding-left: 43.5%;
}
.book button {
  background-color: #F6B2A2; 
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
.book a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="top">
  <div class="socialm">
    <h2>Social Media</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="page2.php"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <a href="page2.php"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="book">
  <a href="page2.php"><button>Book</button></a>
</div>
```